# Как правильно выбрать данные по двух условиям?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица ad - [структура](http://joxi.ru/DmBPedpi4DL8kA) и таблица ad_props - [структура](http://joxi.ru/5mdqpR8S8oz6o2)

Я пытаюсь выбрать запись

```
SELECT `ad`.* 
FROM `ad` 
INNER JOIN `ad_props` ON ad_props.ad_id = ad.id 
WHERE (`status`=2)
  AND ((`ad_props`.`row_id`=5)
  AND ((`ad_props`.`value`='10') OR (`ad_props`.`value_id`='10')))
  AND ((`ad_props`.`row_id`=6)
  AND ((`ad_props`.`value`='12') OR (`ad_props`.`value_id`='12'))) 
GROUP BY `ad`.`id`
```

И должно было выбрать 1 запись - [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://joxi.ru/8AnqD8vSyeJnl2)

Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что не может быть row_id и 5 и 6 одновременно.

Вопрос: с помощью какой конструкции это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `ad`.* 
FROM `ad` 
INNER JOIN `ad_props` ON ad_props.ad_id = ad.id 
WHERE (`status`=2)
  AND
(
 (
      ((`ad_props`.`row_id`=5)
  AND ((`ad_props`.`value`='10') OR (`ad_props`.`value_id`='10')))
 )
 OR
 (
      ((`ad_props`.`row_id`=6)
  AND ((`ad_props`.`value`='12') OR (`ad_props`.`value_id`='12'))) 
 )
)
GROUP BY `ad`.`id`
```

Comment: спасибо большое